# Zero padding not performed properly I think

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, regression, recurrent-neural-network

I seem to have some issues using the implementation that is provided [here](https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/). 
I am a bit in a similar situation as the guy posting, in which I am trying to map and input to an output. The input being samples of an audio file, and the output being a feature vector with length 14 (length is static). The sequence length is variable as the audio files are in different lengths, making the vector containing the samples become in different lengths as well.

I am not solving a classification problem but a regression, so a bit different task.

My code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn_cell
from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn
import numpy as np
import librosa
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os
from os import walk
from os.path import splitext
from os.path import join
import time
rng = np.random
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
import functools

start_time = time.time()

print "Preprocessing"

def lazy_property(function):
    attribute = '_' + function.__name__

    @property
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(self):
        if not hasattr(self, attribute):
            setattr(self, attribute, function(self))
        return getattr(self, attribute)
    return wrapper
## Class definition ##
class VariableSequenceLabelling:

    def __init__(self, data, target, num_hidden=200, num_layers=3):
        self.data = data
        self.target = target
        self._num_hidden = num_hidden
        self._num_layers = num_layers
        self.prediction
        self.error
        self.optimize

    @lazy_property
    def length(self):
        used = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(self.data), reduction_indices=2))
        length = tf.reduce_sum(used, reduction_indices=1)
        length = tf.cast(length, tf.int32)
        return length

    @lazy_property
    def prediction(self):
        # Recurrent network.
        output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
             rnn_cell.GRUCell(self._num_hidden),
            self.data,
            dtype=tf.float32,
            sequence_length=self.length,
        )
        # Softmax layer.
        max_length = int(self.target.get_shape()[1])
        num_classes = int(self.target.get_shape()[2])
        weight, bias = self._weight_and_bias(self._num_hidden, num_classes)
        # Flatten to apply same weights to all time steps.
        output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, self._num_hidden])
        prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(output, weight) + bias)
        prediction = tf.reshape(prediction, [-1, max_length, num_classes])
        return prediction

    @lazy_property
    def cost(self):
        # Compute cross entropy for each frame.
        cross_entropy = self.target * tf.log(self.prediction)
        cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, reduction_indices=2)
        mask = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(self.target), reduction_indices=2))
        cross_entropy *= mask
        # Average over actual sequence lengths.
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, reduction_indices=1)
        cross_entropy /= tf.cast(self.length, tf.float32)
        return tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

    @lazy_property
    def optimize(self):
        learning_rate = 0.0003
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
        return optimizer.minimize(self.cost)

    @lazy_property
    def error(self):
        mistakes = tf.not_equal(
            tf.argmax(self.target, 2), tf.argmax(self.prediction, 2))
        mistakes = tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32)
        mask = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(self.target), reduction_indices=2))
        mistakes *= mask
        # Average over actual sequence lengths.
        mistakes = tf.reduce_sum(mistakes, reduction_indices=1)
        mistakes /= tf.cast(self.length, tf.float32)
        return tf.reduce_mean(mistakes)

    @staticmethod
    def _weight_and_bias(in_size, out_size):
        weight = tf.truncated_normal([in_size, out_size], stddev=0.01)
        bias = tf.constant(0.1, shape=[out_size])
        return tf.Variable(weight), tf.Variable(bias)

#######################
#Converting file to .wav from .sph file format... God dammit!!!

#with open(train_filelist, 'r') as train_filelist, open(test_filelist, 'r') as test_filelist:
    #train_mylist = train_filelist.read().splitlines()
    #test_mylist = test_filelist.read().splitlines()
    #for line in train_mylist:
        #new_line = ' '.join(reversed(line))
        #index_start = new_line.find('h')
        #index_end = new_line.find('/')
        #edited_line = ''.join(reversed(new_line[index_start+5:index_end])).strip().replace(" ","")
        #new_file = edited_line + 'wav'
        #os.system(line + ' >> ' + dnn_train + new_file)
    #for line in test_mylist:
        #new_line = ' '.join(reversed(line))
        #index_start = new_line.find('h')
        #index_end = new_line.find('/')
        #edited_line = ''.join(reversed(new_line[index_start+5:index_end])).strip().replace(" ","")
        #new_file = edited_line + 'wav'
        #os.system(line + ' >> ' + dnn_test + new_file)


path_train =  "/home/JoeS/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train"
path_test =  "/home/JoeS/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/test"
dnn_train = "/home/JoeS/kaldi-trunk/dnn/train/"
dnn_test = "/home/JoeS/kaldi-trunk/dnn/test/"
dnn = "/home/JoeS/kaldi-trunk/dnn/"
path  = "/home/JoeS/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/"
MFCC_dir = "/home/JoeS/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/mfcc/raw_mfcc_train.txt"

train_filelist = path_train+"/wav_train.txt"
test_filelist = path_test+"/wav_test.txt"

os.chdir(path)

def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += len(sub) # use start += 1 to find overlapping matches

def load_sound_files(file_paths ,  names_input, data_input):
    raw_sounds = []
    names_output = []
    data_output = []
    class_output = []
    for fp in file_paths:
        X,sr = librosa.load(fp)
        raw_sounds.append(X)
        index = list(find_all(fp,'-'))
        input_index = names_input.index(fp[index[1]+1:index[2]])
        names_output.append(names_input[input_index])
        data_output.append(data_input[input_index])
        class_output.append(binify(data_input[input_index][0]))
    return raw_sounds, names_output, data_output, class_output

def generate_list_of_names_data(file_path):
    # Proprocess
    # extract name and data
    name = []
    data = []
    with open(MFCC_dir) as mfcc_feature_list:
        content = [x.strip('\n') for x in mfcc_feature_list.readlines()] # remove endlines
        start_index_data = 0
        end_index_data = 2
        for number in range(0,42):
            start = list(find_all(content[start_index_data],'['))[0]
            end = list(find_all(content[end_index_data],']'))[0]
            end_name = list(find_all(content[start_index_data],' '))[0]
            substring_data = content[start_index_data][start+1 :]+content[end_index_data][: end]
            substring_name = content[start_index_data][:end_name]
            arr = np.array(substring_data.split(), dtype = float)
            data.append(arr)
            name.append(substring_name)
            start_index_data = start_index_data + +3
            end_index_data = end_index_data +3
    return name, data

files_train_path = [dnn_train+f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
files_test_path = [dnn_test+f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]

files_train_name = [f for f in listdir(dnn_train) if isfile(join(dnn_train, f))]
files_test_name = [f for f in listdir(dnn_test) if isfile(join(dnn_test, f))]

os.chdir(dnn_train)

train_name,train_data = generate_list_of_names_data(files_train_path)
train_data, train_names, train_output_data, train_class_output = load_sound_files(files_train_path,train_name,train_data)

max_length = 0 ## Used for variable sequence input

for element in train_data:
    if element.size > max_length:
        max_length = element.size

NUM_EXAMPLES = len(train_data)/2

test_data = train_data[NUM_EXAMPLES:]
test_output = train_output_data[NUM_EXAMPLES:]

train_data = train_data[:NUM_EXAMPLES]
train_output = train_output_data[:NUM_EXAMPLES]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
##-------------------MAIN----------------------------##

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, 1])
    target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 14, 1])
    model = VariableSequenceLabelling(data, target)
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for epoch in range(10):
        for sample_set in range(100):
            batch_train = train_data[sample_set]
            batch_target = train_output[sample_set]
            sess.run(model.optimize, {data: batch_train, target: batch_target})
        test_set = test_data[epoch]
        test_set_output = test_output[epoch]
        error = sess.run(model.error, {data: test_set, target: test_set_output})
        print('Epoch {:2d} error {:3.1f}%'.format(epoch + 1, 100 * error))
```

And the error message is

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tensorflow_datapreprocess_mfcc_extraction_rnn.py", line 239, in <module>
        sess.run(model.optimize, {data: batch_train, target: batch_target})
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
        run_metadata_ptr)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 553, in _run
        % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
    ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (63945,) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 138915, 1)'
```

The error message I receive, as I understand is due to the use of max_length, and getting an input that does not have the proper size - meaning that the input isn't being zero padded properly?.. Or am I wrong? If so how do I fix it? The solution I seek doesn't seem to come natively from tensorflow, does other framework do this natively - and would it be recommendable to use a different one due to the missing function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shapes of Tensorflow placeholders must match the shapes of data that is fed to them. Here, you're trying to feed a [63945] tensor to a [?, 138915, 1] shaped placeholder. These are incompatible shapes and Tensorflow complains.

You must pad the input tensor using numpy to the desired shape before feeding it to Tensorflow. I suggest using `numpy.pad`. (Also note the number of dimensions must match --- you can use `numpy.reshape` to fix that, or change the placeholder shape and use a Tensorflow reshape.)

When working with long sequences, often padding to a common sequence length can cause memory problems. The standard workaround for that is to bucket sequences into buckets of similar lengths. The Tensorflow seq2seq example might be a useful source of inspiration: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html